# I want to determine the cause of a sigsegv

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib

I'm writing an applicaiton for gentoo linux and redhat linux, one of the funciton always crashes on the redhat machine

```
usleep(100000);
    Display *display;
    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window w;
    int x,y,i;
    unsigned m;
    Window root = XDefaultRootWindow(display);
    XQueryPointer(display,root,&root,&w,&x,&y,&i,&i,&m);
    XImage *image;
    sleep(1);
    image = XGetImage(display,root,0,0,1366,768,AllPlanes,XYPixmap);
    int pixel = XGetPixel(image,x,y);
    printf("\\clr(%i,%i,%i){}\n",x,y,pixel);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
```

This function always crashes with a segmentation fault on the rhel machine

running the progrma in gdb:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000369942cb48 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install atk-1.30.0-1.el6.x86_64 cairo-1.8.8-6.el6_6.x86_64 expat-2.0.1-11.el6_2.x86_64 fontconfig-2.8.0-5.el6.x86_64 freetype-2.3.11-15.el6_6.1.x86_64 gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.1-6.el6_7.x86_64 glib2-2.28.8-4.el6.x86_64 glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.1.x86_64 gtk2-2.24.23-6.el6.x86_64 libX11-1.6.0-6.el6.x86_64 libXau-1.0.6-4.el6.x86_64 libXcomposite-0.4.3-4.el6.x86_64 libXcursor-1.1.14-2.1.el6.x86_64 libXdamage-1.1.3-4.el6.x86_64 libXext-1.3.2-2.1.el6.x86_64 libXfixes-5.0.1-2.1.el6.x86_64 libXi-1.7.2-2.2.el6.x86_64 libXinerama-1.1.3-2.1.el6.x86_64 libXrandr-1.4.1-2.1.el6.x86_64 libXrender-0.9.8-2.1.el6.x86_64 libXtst-1.2.2-2.1.el6.x86_64 libpng-1.2.49-2.el6_7.x86_64 libselinux-2.0.94-5.8.el6.x86_64 libxcb-1.9.1-3.el6.x86_64 pango-1.28.1-10.el6.x86_64 pixman-0.32.4-4.el6.x86_64 zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64

unfortunately I cannot install any additional packages(or install from 3rd party repos) for the rhel machines

backtrace:
(gdb) bt

## 0  0x000000369942cb48 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6

## 1  0x00000000004048ce in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe148) at tat.c:92

line 92 is :
    int pixel = XGetPixel(image,x,y);

the application works fine if that line is removed

thanks

Comment: BTW, You know `int` and `unsigned long` are not the same, right?

Comment: Also, why don't you check for NULL return for `XOpenDisplay()`?

Comment: There is plenty of error handling missing from your code.

Comment: Use XGetWindowAttributes to find the real width/heitgh of the screen. Do not use hardcoded values.

Comment: Besides checking for `NULL` as commented, the man page for `XGetPixel` says *The image must contain the x and y coordinates.* Which you have not checked.

Comment: all valid points, I'll work on them thanks

Comment: You're not checking the values returned by `XQueryPointer(display,root,&root,&w,&x,&y,&i,&i,&m);` and you're just blindly using the value returned by `image = XGetImage(display,root,0,0,1366,768,AllPlanes,XYPixmap);`.  Either one of those calls could fail.

Comment: @fukanchik, yes that was it
thanks, please post this as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XGetWindowAttributes` to find the real width/heitgh of the screen. Do not use the hardcoded values.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is this line returning NULL:

```
image = XGetImage(display,root,0,0,1366,768,AllPlanes,XYPixmap);
```

[Manual Page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xgetimage) says: *If a problem occurs, XGetImage returns NULL.*

However, this error might be triggered by a previous line's error -- as is mentioned in the comments, you should be checking the return values of all these calls for success/failure.